# Efeito "Fade in e Delete - VBA"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

por gentileza, estou com uma dúvida no VBA - MS EXCEL 2016

Eu preciso criar uma macro que quando eu a aciono, ela busca uma imagem.png em meu computador e insere-a sobre a planilha com o efeito gradativo de Fade-in. Após isso, a imagem deve aparecer por 3 segundos e deve ocorrer o efeito de "Delete" desa imagem, para não atrapalhar a edição da planilha.

Tentei vários metodos de macro para essa solução, e sempre algo da errado.

Por gentileza, voces poderiam me ajudar com a codificação?

Muito obrigado!

OBS: O código que eu estava usando era:

```
Sub Imagem_na_Planilha()

 Dim Plan As Worksheet, Imagem As Shape
 Dim Clear As Double
 Set Plan = ActiveSheet
 Set Imagem = Plan.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Downloads\gg.PNG", msoFalse, msoCTrue, 50, 100, 170, 70)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que ao inserir como Shape de imagem, a alteração da transparência não é possível. Você precisa antes inserir um AutoShape.

## Passos

1. Criar um AutoShape na Planilha Ativa (um retângulo ou outra forma)
2. Preencher o Shape com a imagem desejada
3. Loop de alterar a transparência para causar o efeito de Fade in
4. Esperar 3000 ms e apagar a imagem

## Código

Segue o código com um exemplo de como realizar isto:

```
Option Explicit
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub Imagem_na_Planilha()

    Dim Plan As Worksheet, Imagem As Shape
    Dim I As Long

    Set Plan = ActiveSheet
    Set Imagem = Plan.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 100, 170, 70)
    Imagem.Name = "imagem"
    Plan.Shapes("imagem").Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture "C:\TestFolder\imagem.jpeg"
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .Transparency = 1
        'Fade in
        For I = 1 To 100
            .Transparency = 1 - I / 100
            DoEvents
        Next
    End With
    Sleep (3000)
    Plan.Shapes("imagem").Delete
End Sub
```